# Set frame rate to ViewSwitcher alpha animation

Tags: java, android, animation, animated-gif

I have ViewSwitcher with two ImageView. It has crossfade animation (as first appears, the other disappears). It is Done using `AlphaAnimation`, and

```
viewSwitcher.setInAnimation(inAlphaAnimation);
viewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(fadeAlphaAnimation);
```

Is very smooth and nice. But I wanted to make gif from it and so, I took screenshots from a layout to "catch frames" and created a gif from it. It is all good. But I need the animation itself to be like a gif with a frame rate, so it won't be smooth. Is it possible to heave such effect?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched around more and found this:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

> Frame refresh delay: You can specify how often to refresh frames of
>   your animation. The default is set to refresh every 10 ms, but the
>   speed in which your application can refresh frames is ultimately
>   dependent on how busy the system is overall and how fast the system
>   can service the underlying timer.

I found this method that sets frame rate to all animations:

ValueAnimator.setFrameDelay(long frameDelay);

Hope this will help others)

Answer (score 0):

you can improve anim using hardware layers to app

http://blog.danlew.net/2015/10/20/using-hardware-layers-to-improve-animation-performance/

Hope this helps..

Comment: I don't need to improve. I need to decrease frame rate. From 6 to 15 frames per second as user chooses. Thank you)